# Load and Retrain PyTorch model…

Tags: python, pytorch, artificial-intelligence

**Hi all!**  Can you help me?  I have a question: `"How can I retrain a PyTorch model with just a .pt file ?”`

I've looked at many guides but haven't found the answer.  Everything there has a model class.

I tried to import using torch.load() and others.  But it doesn't work.  When I load the model with torch.load() `I can't get the parameters.`[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gqb6w.png)

MyModel class I write myself? Doesn't it have to match the class in .pt?